# Repeating drawLine() to draw vertical bars Java

Tags: java, swing, draw, paintcomponent

I was given an assignment and have been able to complete it, but I feel there must be a easier way to complete it.

I was tasked to draw 60 vertical bars with a width of 5 and random heights.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    super.paintComponent( g );
    g.setColor( color );
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int x, h;

// bar with a width of 5 and random heights

    h = rd.nextInt(height); //random height
    x = 50;


g.drawLine( x, height, x, height-h ); //Bar 1
g.drawLine( x+1, height, x+1, height-h );
g.drawLine( x+2, height, x+2, height-h );
g.drawLine( x+3, height, x+3, height-h );
g.drawLine( x+4, height, x+4, height-h );

g.drawLine( x+6, height, x+6, height-h -12 ); // Bar 2
g.drawLine( x+7, height, x+7, height-h -12 );
g.drawLine( x+8, height, x+8, height-h -12 );
g.drawLine( x+9, height, x+9, height-h -12 );
g.drawLine( x+10, height, x+10, height-h -12);
```

What I have done is just repeat this for all 60 bars and just change the offset at the end of height-h +/- *** and left a space of 1 between bars

This seems like a very long way to do this. Any suggestions on how to implement this without repeating it 60 times.

Edit: Added an image of the final project.
Here is the finished look ![1]

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ivpM.png`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the other answers, no one states the obvious:
**To draw 60 bars, you don't need to draw more than 60 items** (certainly not 60x5=300 lines).

Your options:

- draw the bars as **filled rectangles**
- draw the bars as **lines with a width of 5**

Also the bar values should not be calculated while painting, they're supposed to be the data model.

```
public class Bars extends JPanel {

    private double[] barValues;
    private final static int BAR_WIDTH = 5;
    private final static int BAR_GAP = 3;

    public Bars () {
        barValues = new double[60];
        for (int i = 0; i < barValues.length; i++) {
            barValues[i] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Painting using rectangles:**

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    Dimension size = getSize();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    g.setColor(new Color(0x445566));

    for (int i = 0; i < barValues.length; i++) {
        int h = (int) Math.round(barValues[i] * size.height);
        int x = (i * (BAR_WIDTH + BAR_GAP));
        int y = size.height - 1 - h;
        int w = BAR_WIDTH;
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

**Painting using lines of width 5**:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {

    Dimension size = getSize();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    g.setColor(new Color(0x445566));

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));

    for (int i = 0; i < barValues.length; i++) {
        int h = (int) Math.round(barValues[i] * size.height);
        int x = (i * (BAR_WIDTH + BAR_GAP)) + BAR_WIDTH / 2;
        int y = size.height - 1 - h;
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y + h);
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for being the only person to note that it's insane to call drawLine 5X to make a wide line.  On some platforms, those 5 lines might not even touch! (>1 physical pixel per logical pixel).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop with `%`

```
for(int i = 0, int j = 0 ; i < 360 ; i++ ) {
    if(i % 5 != 0 ) {
        g.drawLine( x+i, height, x+i, height-h - j);
    }

    if(i % 6 = 0)
        j = j - 12;
}
```

I think that's right for what you want. I have made some assumptions:

- You skip every 6th line to leave a space
- You increase j by negative 12 every second line

Comment: I changed this a bit and it seems to work best, but not perfect. It produces the bars but they were all the same size. The -12 in my op was just an example. The bars heights should all be random. I changed the last if() statement to `if(i % 6 == 0) j = rd.nextInt(height);` This does produce random heights for every bar, but some lines are off as it's not keeping each 5 grouped.

Comment: @CFK That is what I would expect. This solution makes the assumption that after every 5th line, the height of the line changes by 12. I shall post another solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of when to use a loop. To draw the first five lines you need something like this.

```
public void drawLines(int x, int height, int h, int j){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        g.drawLine(x + i, height, x + i, height - h - j);
    }
}
```

However, this is not complete because you have to do this multiple times. just use another for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12, i++){
    drawLines(x + i * 5, height, h, i * 12);
}
```

Comment: You have missed out that j needs to be reduced by negative 12 every line.

Comment: no I haven't, look at the final parameter of what is passed into drawLines. it decreases by 12 in every iteration.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 12, i++){` means you draw two lines than reduce j. Or am I reading that wrong? I did the same in my answer, I think you meant `i< 5`

Comment: You call the drawLines method, which draws 5 lines at the same value of j. Then you draw a new 5 lines with the decreased value of j. This happens 12 times because you mentioned you wanted 60 lines drawn. It seems logical to break them into 5 lines at a time which is why the drawLines method is called 12 times.

Comment: The first part works perfect. The second part is twisting the lines.

Comment: ahh, there is a double negative here. modified i * -12 to I * 12

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use for loop and bunch of if statements!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
if( i < 5) {

}
if( i > 5 && i < 10) {
}
// etc..
}
```

Comment: Would that end up with ALOT of `drawLines` which is what the OP wants to reduce?

Comment: Well what about double for loops

Comment: I'll try to prepare an example for you ^^

Comment: Look in the example that I gave you the number of drawLine reduced to 12, I prepare a new example but I don't know exactly your need, you should explain it much more

Answer (score 0):

This is the second try :P

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

```
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        System.out.println("getWidth = " + getWidth());
        System.out.println("getHeight = " + getHeight());
        Random rd = new Random();
        int x = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {

            int fisrt = (i / 12) * 12;

            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {

                int h = rd.nextInt(height); // random height

                g.drawLine(x + j, height, x + j, height - h - fisrt);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This misses the fact the line needs a width of 5. And why do you divide `fisrt` by 12 and then times it by 12?

Comment: drawLine method don't specify the width of the line...
i divid by 12 and multiply by 12 to get the multiples of 12 (12, 24,...)

Comment: It does not no. But the original question code asks that the line be 5 pixels thick.

Comment: This only does displays one bar. I did add image to the OP to show what it should look like. This is also using a GUI so no need for the println. The bar is also being displayed wider than 5.

Comment: you can use fillRect methed

Comment: It seem that I have to use drawLine instead of fillRect.

Answer (score 0):

**What you saw but didn't know it**

You saw a pattern of repeating code. In time and probably after an algorithm class you should be able to pre-predict patterns, some are obvious some are not. This is where reasoning, deductive and math skills come in. Which goes in the order of:

I am repeating myself...

- Why am I repeating this
- Is this is a basic pattern?
- If I am not seeing a basic pattern...can this code be broken down further?
- What is changing increase/decreasing on each same line of code
- What coding idiom (loop, do-while,collection etc) do I know that best deals with this

This is also why keeping code methods short and to the point allows you to see the above more clearly.

But more important before you code: design your objects beforehand. This will allow you to solve 99 problems before you even have to deal with the coding aspect.

*A good design can work in any code of that type (in this case OO/object orientated).*

(Some might argue to keep the second loop in the code below to its separate method to keep it clean, readable and allow you to reuse it again.)

**Your Solution**

Create a method to get your barWidth and this should be your whole paintComponent method. Everything is commented and all variables are clearly defined in what they do, but if you require any help understanding any part do say.

I am not sure why you have rd as a global field.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {

    // Carry out super first
    super.paintComponent( g );

    // Set all field types at start
    int totalWidth, totalHeight, barHeight, barWidth, totalBarsRequired;

    // Set all constant fields
    barWidth = 5; // THE BAR WIDTH IS SET HERE (Create a method)

    // Set all method fields
    totalWidth = getWidth();
    totalHeight = getHeight();
    // No need to set the bars as we can calculate them from the bar width
    totalBarsRequired = (int) totalWidth / barWidth;

    // Look over all the bars required
    for( int barNumber = 0 ; barNumber < totalBarsRequired ; barNumber++ ) {
        // Set a new random height each bar
        barHeight = rd.nextInt( totalHeight );

        // Create the lines and loop until the barWidth has been met
        for (int barLineNumber = 0 ; barLineNumber < barWidth ; barLineNumber++ ) {
            g.drawLine( (barNumber * barWidth) + barLineNumber, barHeight, (barNumber * barWidth) + barLineNumber, barHeight );
        }
    }
}
```